# What is wrong with my solution of this simple probability problem and what is the correct proof?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67754654/10908201) on programming SO. I tried to answer it, but struggled to properly prove the point, so I'm asking here now.

The person asking the initial question noticed that when you generate $N$ random numbers from 1 to $N$, the amount of unique numbers limits to $0.632...  \cdot N$, and they (and now me as well) were interested in why is it so, and what is that constant.

My incorrect solution goes as follows:

> Suppose we put $N$ objects into $N$ boxes. Boxes with exactly one object in it will correspond to numbers generated exactly once, i.e. unique numbers. For any single box the chance to have one object is:
>
> - $\frac 1N$ (probablility of one object being put into this box)
> - $\times \left(\frac{N-1}N\right)^{N-1}$ (probability of all other objects being put into a differrent box)
> - $\times \binom 1 N = \times N$ (picking which one of the objects goes into the selected box)
>
> Which gives the overall probablilty is equal to $p_N = \left(1-\frac 1N\right)^{N-1}$, which limits to $\frac 1 e$. Now we declare a random variable $X$ to be 1, if there is one object in our box and 0 otherwise. Its expected value $\mathbb{E}X$ is obviously equal to $p_N$, and now we say that for all the boxes this expected value is the sum of $\mathbb{E}$ for individual boxes, therefore getting that $\mathbb{E}\text{[#unique numbers]} \sim p_N \cdot N$.

The problem is that $\frac 1e$ is not equal to 0.632..., although $1-\frac 1 e$ is (but this doesn't mean much since $\frac 2 \pi$ or any other expression matches as well). So what am I missing and how to actually prove this?

(I understand the topic of this question is very general and what I'm asking is probably a well-known thing, but I was unable to find it on the Internet.)

Comment: Clarify... are you asking for the number of numbers who appear at least once?  So if the numbers generated were $1,2,2,3$ there would be three numbers appearing in that list?  (*1,2, and 3?*)  Or are you asking for the number of numbers who appear in the list exactly once?  So if the numbers generated were $1,2,2,3$ there would be two numbers in that list appearing exactly once (*namely 1 and 3*)?

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh. Yeah, it turns out I mean 1, 2 and 3, which instantly shows my mistake, so you've answered it :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability that object is not picked this turn is $\frac{N-1}{N}$.
If you pick like this with replacing, then the probability that object is not picked after N turns is $(\frac{N-1}{N})^N$, which if N->$\infty$, limits to $\frac{1}{e}$.

Finally, the probability that it is picket at least once is then $1 - \frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Well, you weren't the first one to answer, but I'll give you some reputation :)